# F# run Task and Wait for completion without throwing errors

Tags: azure, f#

I'm trying to run a task to save a document in Azure via F#, and I want to be able to have any exceptions thrown by the task not immediately throw on the calling thread, but instead use the Task object to see if there was an error and handle it appropriately.

```
let update (c : CoolObjectName) =
    let uri = documentUri c.id
    let t = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(uri, c)
            |> Async.AwaitTask
            |> Async.StartAsTask
```

If this errors, it is throwing that error immediately.

I am not sure if `Async.StartAsTask` is awaiting anything. I'm not entirely sure at what points here, if any, I'm actually waiting for the task to complete. `t` here is of type `Task<SomeAzureThing>`. I later inspect it to see if it's faulted, but that doesn't guarantee it won't fail.

I don't need the response object, I only need the error message if the `Task` fails.

I *can* do `Async.RunSynchronously`, but that will cause any exception thrown to be thrown on the calling thread. I've tried using `t.Wait()`, but `Wait()` will throw any exceptions encountered.

**EDIT**

Regarding converting to/from Task & Async. This is not an intentional design decision, but I am trying to get to a point where I have a way to (1) retrieve the result of the function call or (2) know the function call errored without actually throwing that error. The best way I know how to do this is via a Task. If I don't do this unnecessary conversion, I end up with an `Async<Choice<int,exn>>`:

```
let t = client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(uri, c)
               |> Async.AwaitTask
               |> Async.Catch
```

And I don't seem to have a way to "get" the result of that catch without `Async.RunSynchronously`, which throws exceptions.

Comment: Why are you converting the `Task` into an `Async` only to immediately convert it back into a `Task`?

Comment: @Lee `client.ReplaceDocumentAsync` returns a task, and I can't find any way to start a task without doing the conversions.

Comment: The convention is that methods ending in `Async` return you a running task so you shouldn't need to start it. You can just call `.Start` on it if that's not the case though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Async.Catch` [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/) is the function you want?

> Creates an asynchronous computation that executes a specified
> computation. If this computation completes successfully, then this
> method returns Choice1Of2 with the returned value. If this computation
> raises an exception before it completes then return Choice2Of2 with
> the raised exception.

Comment: This seems like it should do exactly what I need. I will update the main post with the issues I'm having trying to use it.